# Properly Writing an Obfuscator

Tags: python, automation, obfuscation

At the moment I am trying to write an obfuscator. I have been doing some research online for how to create well obfuscated code:
http://p-nand-q.com/programming/obfuscation/python/more.html
Right now I have my obfuscator reading the file and then encrypting it. However this can be easily reversed. So whats a good way to detect classes and functions and not corrupt them? Or is there an even better way to quickly obfuscate it:
https://researchspace.auckland.ac.nz/bitstream/handle/2292/3491/TR148.pdf
I've also been reading this article, and while I mostly understand what the concept or end goals are, I'm having a rough time translating it into actual python script.
I wanted to ask for help with `finding and reading classes names` and if there where any other good techniques for obfuscating.

Comment: If you want to do this sensibly, you need to parse the Python code so you can detect classes and functions.   Too long to put here as a comment.  See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators for details.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll take a look, so far I've been using regular expressions to find stuff. Ill go have to say what the article says.